# Open some items in UIWebView, and others in external browser

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I'm creating a html5 app, embed in UIWebView. I have delegate webview to controller, and on shouldStartLoadWithRequest, I'm looking for url pattern to open or not on external browser.

It's work perfect!

But when phone has no connection, I'm loading local html file. Because shouldStartLoadWithRequest return FALSE on first request, offline.html not loading

Anyone has do that?

[image]

Comment: Please add code to your question as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry, but my xcode is inside a VMbox!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I'm not triggering error -1003 (no host found)! removing switch work perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Try this immediately after set path :

```
do {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("offline", ofType: "html", inDirectory:"offline")
    let string = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    webView.loadHTMLString(string, baseURL: NSURL(string: "http://"))
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

or

```
let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("offline", ofType:"html", inDirectory: "offline")!)
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url);
webView.loadRequest(request);
```

I tried it and it works.

**Make sure your "offline" directory is a folder (BLUE) and not a group (YELLOW).**

Hope this help.

Comment: First solution, is a good solution, but doesn't work. offline.html does white screen

Comment: I tried it just now and it works. Retry with my new changes.

Comment: I found my problem. I'm not trigging error -1003 (no host found)! removing switch work perfectly